# multiple definition of a function in templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I saw an interesting thing but couldn't understand why.

```
template<class dataType>
Class A
{
AFnc();
}

template<> A<int>::AFnc() { }
```

Using only specialized template generates an error saying multiple definition of the same function. And it says it was generated at the same place. 
But if I add

```
template<class dataType>
A<dataType>::AFnc()
{
}
```

Then it gets rid of the error.

Why ? Could someone please explain this behavior.

Comment: You need to clean up your syntax. The code at this time is so "dirty" that there's no way to be sure whether it is real or not. Where's the return type for the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(You need to clean up your syntax. I assume that the actual code does not have all those syntax errors.)

Explicit specialization of template function is no longer a template, since it does not depend on any template parameters anymore. From the point of view of One Definition Rule (ODR) it is an "ordinary" function. And, as an "ordinary" function, it has to be *declared* in header file and *defined* only once in some implementation file. You apparently defined your specialization in header file, which is what leads to ODR violation if the header file gets included into multiple translation units (e.g. your "multiple definition" errors).

In your example, `template<> void A<int>::AFnc()` (I added `void` as return type) is no longer a template. This means that this *definition*

```
template<> void A<int>::AFnc() { }
```

must be moved from the header file to some implementation file. Meanwhile, in the header file you have to keep a non-defining declaration for this function

```
template<> void A<int>::AFnc(); // <- note, no function body
```

to let the compiler know that such specialization exists.

In general, remember the simple rule: if your function template still depends on some unspecified template parameters, it is a true template and it has to be *defined* in header file. But once you "fix" all the parameters (by explicit specialization) it is no longer a template. It becomes an ordinary function that has to be *declared* in header file and *defined* only once in some implementation file.

P.S. The above applies to non-inline functions. Inline functions can be (and are usually supposed to be) defined in header files.

P.P.S. The same logic applies to explicit specializations of static data members of template classes.

Comment: ... or declare it `inline`

Comment: I wanted to be able to give +5 for this answer, so very well explained.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you put explicit instantiation in a header file. Then its code is emitted in every translation unit that includes that file. Just move this code

```
template<> A<int>::AFnc() { }
```

to .cpp file and it will be emitted only once.
You dont get this error with template method because rules for implicit instantiation are different.

Comment: "Just moving" it is not enough. The non-defining declaration `template<> A<int>::AFnc();` should be left in header file.